# Django website rendering as a total mess (intermittently, not always)

Tags: django, mobile, browser, web

I have a website built in Django 1.5 that - at times - doesn't load correctly. And by *not loading correctly*, I specifically mean that if I type its url in my samsung s6 edge's mobile browser, I **sometimes** (but not mostly) see the page below. I am clueless regarding why this is happening (not much shows up in my logs), and how I can troubleshoot it. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't include enough information in your post to properly debug your issue. Also, Django is now on version 1.8.5 and it may be possible that your issue has been patched since then.

Posting your source code is the best way to get help on issues like this.

If you are trying to troubleshoot it yourself and your app is using logging properly you should try writing unit tests for the various components that make up your app.

Comment: Thanks prawg. I'm a beginner; I thought this would be one of those obvious issues. Too bad it's not. Source code is too big to paste here, and I don't know where to begin. I suppose I'll let the question linger for a while in case someone can give me a clue where to begin.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. Its really tough to fix anything without seeing the source. There are just so many things that can go wrong.

I would definitely read into logging and unit tests if you aren't familiar with them. They are the best way to debug an app.

Just to throw a couple things out there: It might be useful to check any output from your database from with shell. If the data coming out of the database isn't corrupted its likely that you should check into the template. There may be an issue with non-ascii characters being used and improper usage of unicode.

Hope that helps bit!